# CentOS 7.4 EPEL "Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64" Error

Tags: centos, yum

I installed the EPEL tools via 'yum install epel-release' and now I cannot 'yum update' without getting "Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again" errors.

I found a page from 2014 where the member was receiving similar errors as I.

- [Installing Epel repository on CentOS fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153566/installing-epel-repository-on-centos-fails)

One of the comments states to change the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` to use the `baseurl` instead of the `mirrorlist` as mentioned in another page/answer.

- [How to install PostGIS on Oracle Linux 6.4 x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642071/how-to-install-postgis-on-oracle-linux-6-4-x64/25646883#25646883)

Following the second link, the change seems simple enough but after looking at `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`, there are three baseurl/mirrorlist lines.  I'm not sure whether to update my `[epel]`, `[epel-debuginfo]`, and/or `[epel-source]`.

What is the consequence of me changing all three lines?  This is a production server and I'm avoiding breaking it as I just got it setup and working.

Here is a copy of my `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch 
failovermethod=priority 
enabled=1 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[epel-debuginfo] 
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch/debug 
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-7&arch=$basearch 
failovermethod=priority 
enabled=0 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7 
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source] 
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS 
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-7&arch=$basearch 
failovermethod=priority 
enabled=0 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7 
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: Unreleated note: I blockquoted my file contents.  Should i have used a different method/tag?  It looks sloppy due to the URLs in the file.

Comment: Please state the error you are encountering in your question, not link to someone with a similar error.

Comment: Who is the troll downvoting virtually all questions here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `debuginfo` and `source` repositories are both disabled (`enabled=0`), so there won't be any difference between changing just the `epel` repo or changing all three.  That said, you should probably update all EPEL repository mirrorlists/urls when you update one, in case you ever need to enable any of those repos.

Comment: I modified all three lines and was able to 'yum install htop' without errors.  After success, I installed 'ncdu' but it had a network error but an hour later it was fine.

Comment: It sounds like your network connection or ISP is having problems.

Comment: The above fix allowed me to download some EPEL packages but the experience was intermittent.  Ultimately, I also determined an exemption needed to be made in our firewall.  Our firewall performs SSL Decryption (deliberate man-in-the-middle attacks against internal traffic) to view SSL (HTTPS) traffic.  Once I bypassed SSL decryption for download.fedoraproject.org, I have not received any issues.  The specific package which forced me down the firewall route was fail2ban.  Fun task of the day:  “nslookup download.fedoraproject.org” for a fun surprise.  Makes me love Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS more!